# XML Serialization and iterating

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, dictionary

I have this XML file which have 3 Words.

```
<synset id="n00252662" type="n">
  <lex_filenum>04</lex_filenum>
  <word lex_id="1">purge</word>
  <word lex_id="1">purging</word>
  <word lex_id="1">purgation</word>
  <pointer refs="n01247647">Hypernym</pointer>
  <pointer refs="v00905283" source="3" target="1">Derivationally related form</pointer>
  <pointer refs="v00475647" source="2" target="1">Derivationally related form</pointer>
  <pointer refs="v00475819" source="1" target="2">Derivationally related form</pointer>
  <pointer refs="v00905283" source="1" target="1">Derivationally related form</pointer>
  <pointer refs="n00252894">Hyponym</pointer>
  <def>the act of clearing yourself (or another) from some stigma or charge</def>
</synset>
```

And DictionaryList.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

[XmlRoot("DictionaryList")]
public class DictionaryList
{
    [XmlArray("synsets")]
    [XmlArrayItem("synset")]
    public List<Dictionary> Dict = new List<Dictionary>();

    //string filepath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/gamedata.xml";

    public static DictionaryList Load(string path)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionaryList));

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as DictionaryList;
        }
    }

    //Loads the xml directly from the given string. Useful in combination with www.text.
    public static DictionaryList LoadFromText(string text)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionaryList));
        return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as DictionaryList;
    }
}
```

Then The Dictionary.cs

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Dictionary
{
    public string word;

    public string def;

    public string example;

    public Dictionary()
    {

    }

    public Dictionary(string nme, string Des)
    {
        word = nme;

        def = Des;
    }
}
```

In my Code, the deserializer does not Include the word purging and purgation since the word <- variable is not an Array.

I have tried to make it an array List but I am not sure if the the deserializer will even put the other words if I make an List array word to it.

Plus accessing the the List inside the list is giving me a problem. I want to know if there is an option I can take where I can access or even store the word as an array without altering the XML file.

And this is my main Dictionary file

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;



public class MainDictionary : MonoBehaviour {


DictionaryList DictionaryCollectionNoun;
DictionaryList DictionaryCollectionVerb;
DictionaryList DictionaryCollectionADV;



public InputField SearchField;
public Text NameField;
public Text DetailsField;
public Text DebugText;
public Text ExampleField;


public TextAsset textAssetNoun;
public TextAsset textAssetVerb;
public TextAsset textAssetADV;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {



    //TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("datanoun", typeof(TextAsset));
    //XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument ();
    //xmldoc.LoadXml ( textAsset.text );
    DebugText.text = Application.dataPath;

    textAssetNoun = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("datanoun");
    textAssetVerb = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("dataverb");
    textAssetADV = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("dataadv");
    //XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    //xmldoc.LoadXml(textAsset.text);

    //Example Psuedocode Danzee Mode;
    //var xmlData = @"<DictionaryList><synsets><synset><word>test</word><def>Fun</def></synset></synsets></DictionaryList>";
    DictionaryCollectionNoun = DictionaryList.LoadFromText(textAssetNoun.text);
    DictionaryCollectionVerb = DictionaryList.LoadFromText(textAssetVerb.text);
    DictionaryCollectionADV = DictionaryList.LoadFromText(textAssetADV.text);


    //Debug.Log(Application.dataPath);




    //DebugText.text = xmldoc.ToString();




}

public void ChangeSearch()
{
    //Dictionary Result = new Dictionary("No Result", "No Description");
    //bool nounBool = DictionaryCollectionNoun.Dict.Any(p => p.word == SearchField.text.ToLower()) ? true : false;
    //bool verbBool = DictionaryCollectionVerb.Dict.Any(p => p.word == SearchField.text.ToLower()) ? true : false;
    //bool advbool = DictionaryCollectionADV.Dict.Any(p => p.word == SearchField.text.ToLower()) ? true : false;




    //if (nounBool)
    //{
    //    Result = DictionaryCollectionNoun.Dict.Find(x => x.word == SearchField.text.ToLower());
    //}
    //else if (verbBool)
    //{
    //    Result = DictionaryCollectionVerb.Dict.Find(x => x.word == SearchField.text.ToLower());
    //}
    //else if (advbool)
    //{
    //    Result = DictionaryCollectionADV.Dict.Find(x => x.word == SearchField.text.ToLower());
    //}


    //NameField.text = Result.word1;
    //DetailsField.text = Result.def2;
    //ExampleField.text = Result.example;

}
```

}

Comment: I propose you to parse xml using `XElement` and manually convert it to Dictionary objects.

Comment: It is still the same, The problem is, how can I parse the <word> multiple tag and store them in an array, either using serializer or XElement, it will only read the first <word> tag and will not itterate with the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public class Word
{
    [XmlAttribute("lex_id")]
    public string LexId { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator string(Word word)
    {
        if (word == null)
            return null;
        return word.Value;
    }
}

public class SynsetPointer
{
    [XmlAttribute("refs")]
    public string Refs { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("target")]
    public string Target { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("synset")]
[XmlType("synset")]
public class Synset
{
    public Synset()
    {
        this.Pointers = new List<SynsetPointer>();
        this.Words = new List<Word>();
    }

    [XmlElement("lex_filenum")]
    public int LexFilenum { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("word")]
    public List<Word> Words { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<string> WordValues { get { return (Words == null ? null : Words.Select(w => (string)w)); } }

    [XmlElement("pointer")]
    public List<SynsetPointer> Pointers { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("def")]
    public string Definition { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("DictionaryList")]
public class DictionaryList
{
    public DictionaryList()
    {
        this.Dict = new List<Synset>();
    }

    [XmlArray("synsets")]
    [XmlArrayItem("synset")]
    public List<Synset> Dict { get; set; }

    //string filepath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/gamedata.xml";

    public static DictionaryList Load(string path)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionaryList));

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as DictionaryList;
        }
    }

    //Loads the xml directly from the given string. Useful in combination with www.text.
    public static DictionaryList LoadFromText(string text)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionaryList));
        return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as DictionaryList;
    }
}
```

I renamed your `Dictionary` class to `Synset` for clarity, since c# already has various [dictionary classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionarybase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which do something different.

To read multiple `word` elements into an array, declare it as a `List<Word>` in the `Synset` class, then apply the [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.  This tells the serializer to expect repeated occurrences of the `word` element rather than a nested list of elements.

This will successfully read and write XML that looks like this:

> ```
> <DictionaryList>
>     <synsets>
>         <synset>
>             <lex_filenum>4</lex_filenum>
>             <word lex_id="1">purge</word>
>             <word lex_id="1">purging</word>
>             <word lex_id="1">purgation</word>
>             <pointer refs="n01247647">Hypernym</pointer>
>             <pointer refs="v00905283" source="3" target="1">Derivationally related form</pointer>
>             <pointer refs="v00475647" source="2" target="1">Derivationally related form</pointer>
>             <pointer refs="v00475819" source="1" target="2">Derivationally related form</pointer>
>             <pointer refs="v00905283" source="1" target="1">Derivationally related form</pointer>
>             <pointer refs="n00252894">Hyponym</pointer>
>             <def>the act of clearing yourself (or another) from some stigma or charge</def>
>         </synset>
>     </synsets>
> </DictionaryList>
> ```

**Update**

To loop through all the text values of all the `Word` classes in all the `Synset` classes in a `DictionaryList`, you can do:

```
        var testXml = @"<DictionaryList> <synsets> <synset id=""n00001740"" type=""n""> <lex_filenum>03</lex_filenum> <word lex_id=""0"">entity</word> <pointer refs=""n00001930 n00002137 n04424418"">Hyponym</pointer> <def>that which is perceived or known or inferred to have its own distinct existence (living or nonliving)</def> </synset> </synsets> </DictionaryList>";
        var dict = DictionaryList.LoadFromText(testXml);

        foreach (var synSet in dict.Dict)
        {
            var words = synSet.WordValues.ToList();
            var word0 = (words.Count > 0 ? words[0] : null);
            var word2 = (words.Count > 2 ? words[2] : null);
            // Do something with the words.
        }
```

**Update 2**

To search for a `Synset` containing a given word, you can do:

```
        var word = "entity";
        var Results = dict.Dict.Where(s => s.WordValues.Any(w => w == word)); // Find all synsets containing the word "entity"
        var Result = dict.Dict.FirstOrDefault(s => s.WordValues.Any(w => w == word)); // Find the first synsets containing the word "entity"
```

Comment: Thanks dbc. I will try it now, and give the result

Comment: In the DictionaryList class the public List<Synset> Dict { get; set; } I can't put set on it, but I can put the get;

Comment: @Aizen - I don't understand why you cannot put a `set` on it.  You can leave it as a public field if you prefer, I just changed it to conform with recommended practice.

Comment: I don't get it either, What I know from properties is when you can control the set to control the Properties Write. It is a big ? for me, for now I have replaced it with the new List<Synset>();

Comment: Umm, no Errors. But no Data. I am trying to itterate From or at lease trying to find if there is any data. But I am getting null. I will paste my MainDictionary class Above.

Comment: @Aizen - can you give a complete example of your XML from the root element down to the `<synset>`?  I don't need to see every entry in the dictionary, just two are enough, but it would help to see how the XML file is structured.

Comment: <DictionaryList>
  <synsets>
    <synset id="n00001740" type="n">
      <lex_filenum>03</lex_filenum>
      <word lex_id="0">entity</word>
      <pointer refs="n00001930 n00002137 n04424418">Hyponym</pointer>
      <def>that which is perceived or known or inferred to have its own distinct existence (living or nonliving)</def>
    </synset>

Comment: I just have <DictionaryList> <synsets> <synset>then the items <word> etc </synset></synsets></DictionaryList> the only important thing is the multiple <word> tag to be itterated or at lease stored.

Comment: @Aizen - I can't reproduce your problem -- I was able to deserialize the XML from your comment and also from the `var xmlData = @"<DictionaryList> ...` line in your code.  If you update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then maybe I can help.

Comment: May I ask how are you trying to pull out the Data? For example. Linq. Getting the 2nd word from the <word> tag. If we have <word>hello</word> and another <word>hi</word> How can I get it using Linq process?

Comment: Thanks dbc. I accepted the answer, because I think it is my implementation of your Answer that is something wrong in here. Thank you for providing time and Detailed answer, I will now read the root of the calls that you have I will get better understanding about your answer. I just hope I am doing the correct deserializing cause if not, no matter how precise you answer. It will never work.

Comment: I got it to work with your itteration!!. Thanks DBC. Is there any documentation on how your procedure works? Just want to read on to something like this.

Comment: I forgot to add, now that this class has been totally. replaced. How do I use Find from it? for example I just want to Find(x => x.word = "entity"). will it give me the Element ? with the Definition from it? Sorry, just trying to get by this code.

Comment: Thanks again DBC. a last. All of this works in Console. But failed me in Unity. InvalidOperationException: To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.String) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. I think this Error is because the MainClass that Initialize the Serializer LoadFromText() is Inheriting from MonoBehaviour which makes this error. Even everyclass that is Answered already is Moved out from the MainClass to Initilaize. it is still throwing me the Error. But this Answer is  really good for my Reference. Thanks again.

Comment: public IEnumerable<string> WordValues { get { return (Words == null ? null : Words.Select(w => (string)w)); } }

It is this Line that's the MonoDevelop is not implementing. Which totally make sense to me Now why IEnumerable. But is not equiped I think to carry this logic. With all this information, given. I think I can solve this for myself. With all the reference that you provided me.

Comment: OMG. Understanding your code. Opened up the IEnumerable for MVC further and I fixed the problem instead of using IEnumerable. I used string[] cause Monobehaviour cannot use IEnumerable on XMLparse. And we know that we can only Inherit once, so I can't really take off Monobehaviour I changed the Count to Length. EVERYTHING WORKS GREAT NOW. THANKS THANKS.

Comment: @Aizen - glad that worked out; I'll remember for the future that the XML parser works a bit differently on mono than .Net.

Comment: Added `[XmlIgnore]` on `IEnumerable<string> WordValues` in case this was causing mono some difficulty.