# End of stream encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read multiple objects from a file with this code:

```
List<Alarm> list = new List<Alarm>();
BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("//my File here"))
{
    while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
    {
        list.Add((Alarm)serializer.Deserialize(stream));
    }
}
```

However, everytime I try to run this code, I get an error like "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed". Note that there is a thread existing already which suggests setting the streams position to 0 after each iteration, but that won't work for me obviously, or I would land in an infinite loop.

What am I doing wrong here? The code itself works if I leave out the while loop, but obviously in a file with multiple objects I don't just want to get a single one out of my file, but rather all of them.

Any advice?

Edit: On demand:

Serialization.

```
//Fetches Data from my GUI, creates a valid Alarm object
Alarm alarm = new Alarm(this.noticeBox.Text, date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, (int)this.hourPicker.Value, (int)this.minutePicker.Value);

var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

using (FileStream stream = "//file"))
{
        serializer.Serialize(stream, alarm);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including the code writing the file to start with?

Comment: have you thought about a different approach look at this posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284671/xml-serialization-and-iterating

Comment: How many objects successfully make it to the list? And how many objects should there be?

Comment: how did you serialized the list? as a hole List<T>? if so you just have to read all the file content into a byte array and call just once Deserialize. And not to mention that I recommend to use a StreamReader over your FileStream

Comment: Where is your code for Alarm class ? Provide it please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you have serialized is the List of `Alarm`s (and not a series of individual `Alarm`s), which is more than probable, then you only have to deserialize that:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("//my File here"))
{
   list = (List<Alarm>)serializer.Deserialize(stream));
}
```

Otherwise, if you have serialized standalone `Alarm` objects, your code should work (each of them would be an object graph by itself, which seems not to be the case)

**Edit**: everything in what you posted seems to be fine. I've added a fiddle here ( https://dotnetfiddle.net/bGWOOO ) which demonstrate how the method you are using works (I used a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream` for obvious reasons, but it should not matter). So there's something else wrong: either the stream is not being correctly written to disk, or not being correctly read, but it's not about the code you posted, definitely.

## Update

Just for further reference as to why this answer was chosen (as the real answer was in the comments/chat):

In the serializer, you are creating the file everytime and replacing the contents (not shown in the question, but guessed out in the comments), so the answer was correctly appending to the file, something like this:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("** path to file here**", FileMode.Append,  FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
  // write the serialized data to the stream
}
```

Comment: It's a file filled with Alarm's, not an Alarm-List. I could form it into that way, but I would prefer to do it with single Alarm-Objects.

Comment: @Sossenbinder then something is wrong with the serialization (or with the stream), your deserialization code looks perfectly fine to me. Can you edit the question and add the serialization/writing to file part?

Comment: I've added a fiddle demonstrating the correct behaviour of the code you posted (or a similar one), so there's obviously something else wrong which you haven't shown us

Comment: Thanks so far. Where would I put the file path to the memorystream?

Comment: You don't, I used a `MemoryStream` because I was using a web fiddle for demonstrating purposes (which doesn't allow writing to disk), you should use a `FileStream` as you are doing. `MemoryStream`s don't write to files (as its name implies), but it's basically the same (just in memory, instead of in a file on disk)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84609/discussion-between-sossenbinder-and-jcl).

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a proof of how to serialize / deserialize an object using BinaryFormatter:

List<String> ls = new List<string>();
        ls.Add("aaa");
        ls.Add("Bb");

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ().Replace ("-","");
        var path = Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), fileName);

        try
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                bf.Serialize(fs, ls);
            }

            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                ls = bf.Deserialize(fs) as List<String>;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (File.Exists (path))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just needed to add the Alarms to a list of Alarms before you serialized. This works and seems to do what you want:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Alarm> listYouSerializeInto = new List<Alarm>();
    listYouSerializeInto.Add(new Alarm("test", 2015, 07, 29, 06, 00));
    listYouSerializeInto.Add(new Alarm("test", 2015, 07, 29, 07, 00));
    listYouSerializeInto.Add(new Alarm("test", 2015, 07, 29, 08, 00));

    var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\alarm.bin", FileMode.Create))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, listYouSerializeInto);
    }

    List<Alarm> listYouDeserializeInto = new List<Alarm>(); 
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\alarm.bin", FileMode.Open))
    {

        listYouDeserializeInto = (List<Alarm>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        foreach (Alarm a in listYouDeserializeInto)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }


    }



}

// Define other methods and classes here
[Serializable]
public class Alarm {
    public string Text { get; set;}
    public int Year { get; set;}
    public int Month { get; set;}
    public int Day { get; set;}
    public int Hour { get; set;}
    public int Minute { get; set;}

    public Alarm (string text, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute)
    {
        Text = text;
        Year = year;
        Month = month;
        Day = day;
        Hour = hour;
        Minute = minute;
    }

}
```